# Using data from one datable to calculate values of another datatable

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have a dash data table where a user can input their values. I want to take values from that data table and sum them to find values for another data table.

Data table 1: The data is for 3 months (M1, M2, M3) and each of the numbers under region, state, and city corresponds to an operation that has to be done on the corresponding month of that data. For instance the 4 in (a, state) corresponds to increasing values by 4% in month 1 in parameter 'a'.

```
  region  state  city    date
a   0      4      4     M1 only 
b   2      1      1     M1 and M3
c   4      7      9     M2 only
d   5      3      1     M1 and M2 and M3
```

Data table 2: In this table you would sum up the values in each row of data table 1 with the corresponding operations as described by the 'date' column and then display it in the corresponding row. Pls note that all these values are illustrative and not actual calculations.

```
    A
a   9      
b   19      
c   18     
d   20
```

My code: I am able to generate a second table but I am only able to copy values. I am not able to reach the functionality that I want. I am new to dash and hence need some guidance.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import dash_table
import os
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import numpy as np

names = ['sr no', 'Region', 'state', 'city', 'date']
team_entries = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4,len(names))),columns = names)
team_entries['Pos']=['a', 'b', 'b', 'd']
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='div1', children=[dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table-editing-simple',
        columns=([{'id': p, 'name': p} for p in team_entries.columns]),
        data=team_entries.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True
    )]),
    html.Div(id = 'div2', children=[dash_table.DataTable(id='table-editing-simple-output')])
])


@app.callback(
    Output('div2', 'children'),
    [Input('table-editing-simple', 'data'),
     Input('table-editing-simple', 'columns')])
def display_output(rows, columns):
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=[c['name'] for c in columns])
    return dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table-output',
        columns=columns,
        data=rows,
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```